# jQuery validation remote with symfony 2 url routing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm rewriting some javascript validation using [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

One problem that has occurred is with a function that checks if the username is valid or not.
It does this by sending an ajax call containing the username.

The request URL needs to look like this:

> /ajax/check-username/usernamehere

**Current function:**

```
var checkUsername = function(value){
    var username = false;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/check-username/" + encodeURI(value)
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.exists) {
            username = false;
        } else {
            username = true;
        }
    });
    return username;
}
```

jQuery Validate request path looks like this:

> /ajax/check-username/?username=usernamehere

**jQuery Validation:**

```
jQuery('#user').validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            remote: {
                url: '/ajax/check-username/'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I get the remote method to use my current url routing?

Comment: I edited your tags.  The [tag:jquery-validation-engine] is a totally different plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Your original JavaScript function is looking to see if data exists.

```
if (data.exists) {
    username = false;
} else {
    username = true;
}
```

However, [as per documentation for the `remote` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), you'll need to return `true` from the server script in order to pass validation.  Almost any other response will trigger a validation error message.

> "The response is evaluated as JSON and **must** be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`, `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. 'That name is already taken, try peter123 instead' to display as the error message."

Your best solution would be to modify your server script at `/ajax/check-username/` so that it returns `true` when no data exists; and either `false` or your desired error message otherwise.

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"How can I get the remote method to use my current url routing?"*

Short answer: you don't.

The remote method is sending the data to your server script as JSON `dataType` using the following default settings...

```
dataType: "json",
data: { nameOfTheElement: valueOfTheElement }
```

So you could modify the server script to simply accept the incoming data in this JSON format.

Otherwise, you could change the `remote` settings when you declare it.

An example taken [from the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

```
rules: {
    username: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 6,
        remote: {
            url: "/ajax/check-username/",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                username: function() {
                    return $( "#username" ).val();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the response is not the issue. The issue is, that the URLs are not correct. /ajax/check-username/?username=testusername needs to look like: /ajax/check-username/testusername.

Comment: @CharliePrynn, please read the second half of my answer.  And from the limited code you posted in your question, it looked to me like the response would _also_ be a problem.